# Favicon in Control Panel

Tags: control-panel

I'd like to add my site's favicon to the admin part of the site.

I tried to do this using the "Site icon" option under general settings. That adds the icon to the sidebar but not as a favicon.

The only way I've found that works so far is by editing the CP's base layout template and adding it there, but that's obviously a bad idea, as that will get overwritten on update.

Anyone found another way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a favicon.ico at the base level of your public site I think that should do it. All I can tell you is that this is what works for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me =/

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Craft 3.5+, you can use the [cpHeadTags](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#cpheadtags) config settings to achieve this.

```
'cpHeadTags' => [
    // Traditional favicon
    ['link', ['rel' => 'icon', 'href' => '/icons/favicon.ico']],
    // Scalable favicon for browsers that support them
    ['link', ['rel' => 'icon', 'type' => 'image/svg+xml', 'sizes' => 'any', 'href' => '/icons/favicon.svg']],
    // Touch icon for mobile devices
    ['link', ['rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 'sizes' => '180x180', 'href' => '/icons/touch-icon.svg']],
    // Pinned tab icon for Safari
    ['link', ['rel' => 'mask-icon', 'href' => '/icons/mask-icon.svg', 'color' => '#663399']],
],
```